# Network problem on working days at the same time

Tags: networking, ping

We're running Ubuntu server 14.04 64bit and since 2 weeks it has intermittent network problems (pings get lost, around 50%). Server is running only MySQL database. Weird thing is, it happens only in work days and always around 8:30.
Server has IP assigned by DHCP server (also on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit)
What is the best way to check what is going on?
Everything was working fine for half a year.

Comment: 1) Any there any cron jobs scheduled for that time? 
2) What does network problems mean? Lost connections? Lag? Link going down and back up? ...

Comment: when i ping it, it gives 50-60% packet loss.

Comment: I see the same thing on a daily basis, but haven't got to the bottom of it. I have a cron job write a log message every minute; around those times that the server is unresponsive, cron jobs get executed but minutes later than planned.

Comment: What happens if you ping from other servers on the same switch? And what happens if you ping to servers not on the same switch? (e.g. determine if it is your server/NIC which causes the problems, or the switch (e.g. by it getting flooded by traffic from other servers at 8:30), or the uplink from switch to next hop.

Comment: Just saw the delayed cron job message. If those are not network related then it indeed seems to point to your local server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by employees HTC phone connecting to Wi-Fi. I've managed to find the problem starting unplugging areas from the network, when I've found router is the problem then log showed me who connected at the time of crash. I have written simple app for Raspberry Pi that constantly pings all servers and sends an email to admins so I know exact time of packet loss.

Can anyone explain why just that server had problems with network?